# Android SSL - Not working on API 7

Tags: java, android, ssl, https

I followed this tutorial http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/ and managed to connect to my webservice via HTTPS on Android API 16 (4.1)

My app can use low API, so I launched Google Maps API 7 emulator, but now when I'm trying to connect, it gives me

```
10-13 05:10:47.441: W/System.err(492): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate
```

I launched the 4.1 emulator, and it still works there.

The tutorial is from 2 years ago, not using anything new...

pretty much the same issue as this ["Not trusted Server Certificate" in Android 2.2 but not 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724833/not-trusted-server-certificate-in-android-2-2-but-not-3-0)
but no solution there either...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what caused it, But since I'm using a certificate that I bought, and NOT a self-signed one, I didn't had to do too much tweaking. Just used the `HttpClient` used here

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/31/creating-an-http-client-example/